# how to get dynamic generated src attribute of web element?

Tags: javascript, web

I want to check if our advertisement(picture or flash) has successfully displayed on website page.But the element can not be found in page source.

I get the element in chrome Developer tools.

```
<div id="QQcom_all_Rectangle:1" data-loc="QQcom_all_Rectangle" data-index="1" style="height: 250px; display: block; width: 300px; position: relative;" class="l_qq_com" adconfig_lview="l.qq.com" adconfig_charset="gbk" adconfig_lview_template="http://l.qq.com/lview?c=www&amp;loc={loc}" oid="1800716433" display="banner">
   <a href="http://c.l.qq.com/lclick?loc=QQcom_all_Rectangle&amp;click_data=dXNlcl9pbmZvPW9CM2pnVGd4RnhHNyZhZHhfZXh0PSZwY3RyPTUwMSZhdmVyPTUwMTIwMSZwcmk9eHRiQkZXc0ovclloYXdzdWZqRmpSTkhyZWFuL3pQU2omYnRwcmk9R3VBL25heHhnY3JyNTdrdVNCNW4yWis3TlJqM01nTmw=&amp;oid=1800716433&amp;soid=gmLndBibVj/1bQtQRjKVNkVKAV1Q&amp;dtype=0&amp;pctr=501&amp;aver=501201&amp;btoid=100418428&amp;pri=xtbBFWsJ/rYhawsufjFjRNHrean/zPSj&amp;btpri=GuA/naxxgcrr57kuSB5n2Z+7NRj3MgNl&amp;index=1&amp;page_type=2&amp;chl=703" target="_blank" style="display:block;cursor:pointer;width:300px;height:250px;background-image:url(http://wb.gtimg.com/adwin/f77a7b805584f33e5b539f61e2a7954212856.jpg);background-size:300px 250px;filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='http://wb.gtimg.com/adwin/f77a7b805584f33e5b539f61e2a7954212856.jpg',sizingMethod='scale');"></a>
   <a class="absolute a_cover" href="http://c.l.qq.com/lclick?loc=QQcom_all_Rectangle&amp;click_data=dXNlcl9pbmZvPW9CM2pnVGd4RnhHNyZhZHhfZXh0PSZwY3RyPTUwMSZhdmVyPTUwMTIwMSZwcmk9eHRiQkZXc0ovclloYXdzdWZqRmpSTkhyZWFuL3pQU2omYnRwcmk9R3VBL25heHhnY3JyNTdrdVNCNW4yWis3TlJqM01nTmw=&amp;oid=1800716433&amp;soid=gmLndBibVj/1bQtQRjKVNkVKAV1Q&amp;dtype=0&amp;pctr=501&amp;aver=501201&amp;btoid=100418428&amp;pri=xtbBFWsJ/rYhawsufjFjRNHrean/zPSj&amp;btpri=GuA/naxxgcrr57kuSB5n2Z+7NRj3MgNl&amp;index=1&amp;page_type=2&amp;chl=703&amp;k=%E6%9B%9D%E7%81%AB%E7%AE%AD%E5%B7%B2%E8%A3%81%E6%8E%89%E6%B5%B7%E8%80%B6%E6%96%AF%20%E5%9B%9E%E5%BD%92%E4%BC%91%E5%9F%8E%E4%BB%85%E4%B8%80%E5%91%A8%E5%BE%81%E6%88%982%E5%9C%BA%2C%E6%B5%B7%E8%80%B6%E6%96%AF%2C%E7%81%AB%E7%AE%AD%2CNBA&amp;t=%E6%9B%9D%E7%81%AB%E7%AE%AD%E5%B7%B2%E8%A3%81%E6%8E%89%E6%B5%B7%E8%80%B6%E6%96%AF%20%E5%9B%9E%E5%BD%92%E4%BC%91%E5%9F%8E%E4%BB%85%E4%B8%80%E5%91%A8%E5%BE%81%E6%88%982%E5%9C%BA_&amp;r=&amp;s=" target="_blank" rel="nofollow" style="position:absolute;width:300px;height:250px;left:0px;top:0px;cursor:pointer;z-index:10;background-color:#fff;filter:alpha(opacity=0);opacity:0;"></a>
   <div class="absolute" style="position: absolute; width: 24px; height: 16px; left: 26px; bottom: 0px; cursor: pointer; display: none; z-index: 20; background: url(http://ra.gtimg.com/web/res/icon/report_default_new.png) 50% 0% no-repeat;"></div>
   <div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; bottom: 0px; width: 26px; height: 16px; z-index: 12; background: url(http://ra.gtimg.com/web/res/icon/leftbottom_new.png) 100% 0% no-repeat;"></div>
   <div class="absolute" style="position:absolute;width:18px;height:18px;right:0px;bottom:0px;cursor:pointer;z-index:20;background:url(http://ra.gtimg.com/web/privacy/white_icon.png) no-repeat;"></div>
</div>
```

but in page source,it only shows

```
<!--$loc$_div AD begin...."l=$loc$&log=off"--><div id="QQcom_all_Rectangle:1"  data-loc="QQcom_all_Rectangle" data-index="1" style="height:0;" class="l_qq_com"></div><!--$loc$ AD end --><!--[if !IE]>|xGv00|c5668531d36ed7899852180841ca2aa2<![endif]-->
```

how can I get the 300px_250px image url?

anyone knows?

Comment: this problem is because its getting change in every second you cant handle that how every you can verify that this DIV for adds is showing some thing or not

Answer (score 0):

Yeah! That's simply because of the fact that there are DOM manipulation libraries which alter the Document-Object Markup and not the source.

You have to understand the difference between the DOM and the physical page source. The physical page source helps render the DOM, after which it can be modified by using libraries; since you can't change the source on the server side as it needs to be re-rendered for different people, only the DOM is changed. In very simple words, DOM is what the browser has rendered: it's like a copy of the source which has been, then, modified by the libraries.

Using a library like jQuery can do this easily.

```
var $element = $( "#QQcom_all_Rectangle:1" );
if ( !$element || $element === null ) {
    console.log( "The element hasn't been rendered. Not found.");
}
```

But if it is not YOUR page, and you can't really modify it and/or get the data. You can try doing this with a web-kit emulator like PhantomJS or Selenium web-kit. Since these are just testing frameworks, you can't create a fully fledged JavaScript applications.

Theoretically, you can:

1. Render this in a WebKit (Browser Rendering Component)
2. Get the source of the DOM
3. Use it

But that's just in theory because you need to use some language to create an application like that and since it's outside the scope of your question, you can't.

Comment: share with me link of that web page ?

Comment: i am asking for the web page where you are searching for this control

Comment: I am not the OP. Ask @venus

Answer (score 0):

Using selenium webdriver can handle this.

```
WebElement QQcom_all_Rectangle=driver.findElement(By.id("QQcom_all_Rectangle:1"));
List<WebElement> links=QQcom_all_Rectangle.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
String style=links.get(0).getAttribute("style");
```